# keycloak kc_idp_hint redirect uri always return 401 unauthorised error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, keycloak, openid-connect, claims-based-identity

I'm new to keycloak.
I tried to implement keycloak in my mvc web application, and i placed one anchor tag with href value mentioned in below format. When I click anchor tag it redirect to identity provider site which we configured in keycloak and authentication everything completed successfully and redirect to our application.
While catching response in mvc application method always return 401 unauthorised error.

id-connect/auth?client_id=<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>&redirect_uri=<THE_REDIRECT_URI>&response_type=code&scope=openid&kc_idp_hint=<the_name_that_you_give_to_the_idp>

Comment: when you remove kc_idp_hint param, can you goto the login page?